# How to skip unique values in Postgres DB

Tags: python, postgresql, flask

I have written a Flask app that pulls a list of computers from a JSON api and stores them in the database. Once they are stored, the script fails because it's trying to write the same computers to the database, but I have serial_number unique set to True. Here's the DB structure and function.

Error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

```
class Computer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    serial_number = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    group = db.Column(db.String(80))
    notes = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)

    def __init__(self, serial_number, group, notes):
        self.serial_number = serial_number
        self.group = group
        self.notes = notes

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Computer %r>' % self.serial_number

def save_comps():
    comps = r.json()
    for comp in comps:
        serial = str(comp['serial_number'])
        group = str(comp['group'])
        notes = None
        if comp['serial_number'] != serial:
            c = Computer(serial, group, notes)
            db.session.add(c)
            db.session.commit()
```

As always, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Would this do the trick?

```
 from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
 if comp['serial_number'] != serial:
        c = Computer(serial, group, notes)
        db.session.add(c)
        try:         
            db.session.commit()
        except IntegrityError:
            # handle error here
```

I usually manage integrity errors this way.  If this isn't the logic you want, you might want to reconsider your db design, e.g. update a flag in the model, rather than add the serial number.

For example:

```
class Computer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    serial_number = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    group = db.Column(db.String(80))
    notes = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=True)
    last_registered = db.Column(db.DateTime,default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

Comment: I like where you going with this, but here's my long term goal. When I add a new computer, I want the script to write the new computer to that database and not have multiple instances of the same computer. However, when a computer throws an error, I want it to write to another database using something like `last_regitered`.

Comment: Oh, in that case, use the exception block to write a last_registered timestamp to another datasource.  Each computer will only be represented once (uniqueness is guaranteed), and if a computer is registered a second time, you can catch that and log it.

Comment: I get `global name 'sqlalchemy' is not defined` when I call the exception.

Comment: from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
.
.
except IntegityError:
Should do the trick (instead of the full name)

Comment: I had to add `Session.rollback()`. The strange thing is that primary key id is no longer sequential but adding the value of all the entries listed.